# Trying to replace a different amount of spaces with only one comma

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have a data array with multiple rows that I'm trying to output to a `CSV` file. The input file has a different amount of blank spaces between columns so the columns don't match up with the cells in the excel spreadsheet. When I write,

```
    output.WriteLine(s.Replace(" ", ","));
```

it takes away all blank spaces and replace them with commas making the csv file look terrible. I was wondering if there was a way I could loop through get rid of all the blank spaces and replace them with only one comma instead of many.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You need to make use of regular expressions

Comment: Can we see the code for the `Array` you are speaking of?  How is it parsing its data?

Comment: Do you want to replace all spaces (not other whitespaces character) with just one comma? "abc            def gh\tjk" -> "abc,def,gh\tjk"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Regular Expression to replace multiple spaces

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}");     
var newStr = r.Replace(FileContents, @",");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Regular Expressions, like so:

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", ",");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried both ways but here is my whole code if you both would like to take a look,

```
        foreach (string s in partsComb)
        {
            //s.Split(delimiters);
           // s.Trim();
            partsComb.Equals(s);
            //output.WriteLine(s.Replace("      ", ",")); // takes away all blank spaces and replaces them with comma for the CSV file output

            output.WriteLine(s);
        }
        output.Close();
    }
```